# Updating lucene index - the most popular way

Tags: java, lucene, indexing

I am updating lucene index onec a day. My strategy in general is:

1. Find all objects in DB that was modified since last index generation.
2. Create new tmp-index for these objects. (old index is stil available)
3. Remove all new indexed Documents (they are in tmp-index) from the old index using IndexWriter.deleteDocuments(Term)
4. Merge old index and tmp-index using IndexWriter.addIndexes(...)

I have found that in lucene wiki: [There is no direct update procedure in Lucene...](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_do_I_update_a_document_or_a_set_of_documents_that_are_already_indexed.3F)
I have found also that in lucene 4.1.0 doc: [A document can be updated with updateDocument...](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/index.html)

I have tried IndexWriter.updateDocument(Term, Document) but then performing search with filter I got NPE from one of my methods what not happens when I update index as describe in 1-4. Have anyone had a similar problem? How do you update your index?

Comment: "got NPE from one of lucene methods" -- can you report this to Lucene JIRA or java-users@ mailing list? Could be you ran into a bug.

Comment: No NPE in lucene - my oversight.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is basically this:

I keep a persistent IndexReader/Readers, this will keep the state that it has since it was created.

I start to delete and create all documents once again. I think I just do a deleteAll() and then recreate them (addDocument()).

I commit, which will activate all those changes.

I drop all IndexReaders that I have, so the next time the system request a Reader, it will create it and store it for subsequent requests.

The updateDocument is basically a delete/create, afaik.

Comment: I can't re-index all Documents because it costs to much time. That is the reason for my question.

Comment: Well, the same principle applies, just delete the document that you want to update and then add it. It's when you commit that it will actually be updated, but you must still drop the old IndexReader and create a new one, otherwise it will still be searching in the old index.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `SearcherManager` to get new IndexSearchers as you update the index with a IndexWriter. I see no need for using a temporary index?